# Can I get the violated entry's IRI with API Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a Symfony 5 Project using `symfony/api` (API Platform) with an entity with a `UniqueEntity`constraint (See below. I have omitted field annotations for better lisibility as they are not relevant here.) :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CartItemRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *     itemOperations={"get","patch"},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"cart_item:read"}}
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"product","cart"})
 */
class CartItem
{
    private $id;
    private $product;
    private $quantity;
    private $cart;

    /* ... */
}
```

Let's say I have some data :

```
----------------------------------------
| id | product_id | cart_id | quantity |
|  1 |          3 |       2 |        1 |
|  2 |          2 |       2 |        2 |
----------------------------------------
```

Now If I send this POST request :

```
{
  "product": "/api/products/3",
  "quantity": 1,
  "cart": "/api/carts/2"
}
```

I will of course expect this `400` response because inserting this entry would break the uniqueness of `[product_id,cart_id]` because `[3,2]` is already used by ID 1 :

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
  "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "product: This value is already used.",
  "violations": [
    {
      "propertyPath": "product",
      "message": "This value is already used."
    }
  ]
}
```

My question here is : **Do I have a way to get the IRI or the ID of the entity which would have been "duplicated" ?** (Here, the ID would have been 1, the IRI would have been `/api/cart_items/1`). What I would like to achieve with this is to reproduce MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + :quantity` behaviour, by detecting this error and sending a `PATCH` request if it occurs, but to send a `PATCH` request, I need the IRI, or at least the ID of the item I want to patch.

EDIT :

I have seen in the Profiler that this can be visible (see the `cause` field below) but I can't get in with API's response...

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation {#2332 ▼
  -message: "This value is already used."
  -messageTemplate: "This value is already used."
  -parameters: [▶]
  -plural: null
  -root: App\Entity\CartItem {#675 ▼
    -id: null
    -product: App\Entity\Product {#1888 …}
    -quantity: 1
    -cart: App\Entity\Cart {#2119 …}
  }
  -propertyPath: "product"
  -invalidValue: App\Entity\Product {#1888 …}
  -constraint: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity {#2130 …}
  -code: "23bd9dbf-6b9b-41cd-a99e-4844bcf3077f"
  -cause: [▼
    App\Entity\CartItem {#2330 ▼
      -id: 2
      -product: App\Entity\Product {#1888 …}
      -quantity: 2
      -cart: App\Entity\Cart {#2119 …}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I always use API filters (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/). Before you send a POST request, send a GET request to check if the entity exists. For example, add an annotation for filter:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CartItemRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get","post"},
 *     itemOperations={"get","patch"},
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"cart_item:read"}}
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"product","cart"})
 *
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"product": "exact", "cart": "exact"})
 */
class CartItem
{
    private $id;
    private $product;
    private $quantity;
    private $cart;

    /* ... */
}
```

And use URL for getting existing entity like this: `GET /cart_items?product=3&cart=2` You should get a collection. So, if  `"hydra:totalItems" > 0` from response, you can retrieve an iri from `"hydra:member"[0]`

Comment: Yes, that is the solution I decided to implement, I have come to think that this is the best possible. Too bad we can not spare a request for the cases that wouldn't cause any violation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create your custom](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) **@Assert**, because it is [the only way](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#external-callbacks-and-closures) for you to use the two services which handle that job:

1. **CartItemRepository**,
2. **IriConverterInterface**

First, create the Constraint class **MyUniqueCartItem**. Declare its usage to the class, so that you can access all properties during validation:

```
public function getTargets()
{
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
}
```

Then, create the **MyUniqueCartItemValidator**, and autowire the two previous services to it. Use **CartItemRepository** to check whether the entity already exists, and **IriConverterInterface** to retrieve the IRI:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    // i make it short, just take look ath  the doc
    $criteria = ['cart' => $value->getCart(), 'product' => $value->getProduct()]
    $duplicated = $this->cartItemRepository->findOneBy($criteria);
    if ($duplicated !== null) {
        $iri = $this->iriConverterInterface->getIriFromItem($duplicated);
        $this->context->buildViolation("Duplicated entity : $iri" )
                ->atPath('whatever')
                ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Note that you can make **MyUniqueCartItem** a generic constraint **MyUniqueEntity** by adding some properties to it where you specify what are the needed criteria and repository. Within the **MyUniqueEntityValidator**, replace the **CartItemRepository** by **EntityManagerInterface** and fetch the repository:

```
$repository = $this->entityManger->getRepository($constraint->entityClass);
```